# How to know number of bytes of a Binary File?

Tags: java, binaryfiles, utf, dataoutputstream

How to count number of bytes of this binary file (t.dat) without running this code
(as a theoretical question) ?
Assuming that you run the following program on Windows using the default ASCII encoding.

```
public class Bin {
     public static void main(String[] args){
     DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("t.dat"));
     output.writeInt(12345);
     output.writeUTF("5678");
     output.close();
     }
}
```

Comment: This have nothing to do with OOP. Removed irrelevant tags. Please ensure the tags you use for future questions are justifiable. In fact, this seems like a CS question, where code isn't even required, rather just the information such as language, encoding & the type/amount of data.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to compute the bytes output by each write operation, you could simply check the length of the file after it's closed using `new File("t.dat").length()`.

If you wanted to figure it out without checking the length directly, an `int` takes up 4 bytes, and something written with `writeUTF` takes up 2 bytes to represented the encoded length of the string, plus the space the string itself takes, which in this case is another 4 bytes -- in UTF-8, each of the characters in "5678" requires 1 byte.

So that's 4 + 2 + 4, or 10 bytes.

Comment: This is a theory exam question (on paper) how to count it without running the code ?

Comment: I amended my answer above.

Comment: Note that the details of what `writeUTF` and `writeInt` output are specified in the javadocs.   But this is (IMO) a poor exam question if they expect you to be able to recite details as obscure as these.

Comment: (According to the javadoc writeUTF outputs **exactly** two bytes for the length.   But, interestingly, it doesn't say what happens for a string with > 2^16 characters.   The answer is that it throws `UTFDataFormatException` ...)

Comment: Indeed, anything that uses _modified UTF_ is obscure (except JNI—no, JNI _is_ obscure).